# Set env-var at time of deployment google app engine

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a endpoint application so therefore when i deploy endpoints configuration to google cloud i get a service name and configuration id each time i deploy which i need to set as environment variable at the time of deployment of my app-engine project in app.yaml

app.yaml

```
env_variables:
  ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME: [project-id].appspot.com
  ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_VERSION: 2017-12-28r0
```

so instead of specifying it in app.yaml can i specify in command line at the time of deployment?

I tried to see any such flag or command line argument in gcloud but was not able to find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it needs to be in the app.yaml. That is how the running app gets its environment variables.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I passed them in deploy command directly, but can't find how